# Copying Multiple Label and Textbox Inputs in Powershell GUI to clipboard for pasting

Tags: javascript, powershell

Please Help,

I promised myself that I would get this working on my own, but no matter what I have tried I can't seem to figure it out. I have tried google and so have some colleagues, but to no avail.

Trying to have a GUI run for staff to enter information on jobs that they action so that updates placed into the jobs are following a specific TEMPLATE format.

EXAMPLE:

- A:  Asset Number(s) - Asset number(s) of any affected equipment
  *(Break Line)*
- E:  Error Text - Error message if applicable *(Break Line)*
- I:  Issue Text - What the technician's observation is *(Break

  Line)*
- TT: Test & Tag - Were the power cables T&T compliant *(Break

  Line)*
- TS: Troubleshooting - What steps were performed during the
  resolution *(Break Line)*
- RW: Resolution/Workaround - How you fixed    the problem *(Break
  Line)*

above is the template that would be followed with the text after "A: " (and so on) being filled out by the staff.
The code I currently have can be found below.

```css
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,320)
$Form.MaximizeBox = $false
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
$Form.Text = "Ticket Updates"

# ----------CREATE LABELS---------- #
$AssetLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$AssetLabel.Text = "A:"
$AssetLabel.AutoSize = $true
$AssetLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(21,15)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.Controls.Add($AssetLabel)

$ErrorLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ErrorLabel.Text = "E:"
$ErrorLabel.AutoSize = $true
$ErrorLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(21,50)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.Controls.Add($ErrorLabel)

$IssueLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$IssueLabel.Text = "I:"
$IssueLabel.AutoSize = $true
$IssueLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(21,85)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.Controls.Add($IssueLabel)

$TestTagLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TestTagLabel.Text = "TT:"
$TestTagLabel.AutoSize = $true
$TestTagLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,120)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.Controls.Add($TestTagLabel)

$TroubleshootLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TroubleshootLabel.Text = "TS:"
$TroubleshootLabel.AutoSize = $true
$TroubleshootLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,155)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.Controls.Add($TroubleshootLabel)

$ResolutionLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ResolutionLabel.Text = "RW:"
$ResolutionLabel.AutoSize = $true
$ResolutionLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,190)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.Controls.Add($ResolutionLabel)
# ----------END LABELS---------- #

# ----------CREATE TEXT BOXES---------- #
$AssetText = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$AssetText.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(750,20)
$AssetText.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,12)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$AssetText.Text = "<Asset Number(s)> - Asset number(s) of any affected equipment"
$Form.Controls.Add($AssetText)

$ErrorText = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$ErrorText.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(750,20)
$ErrorText.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,47)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$ErrorText.Text = "<Error Text> - Error message if applicable"
$Form.Controls.Add($ErrorText)

$IssueText = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$IssueText.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(750,20)
$IssueText.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,82)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$IssueText.Text = "<Issue Text> - What the technician's observation is"
$Form.Controls.Add($IssueText)

$TestTagText = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TestTagText.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(750,20)
$TestTagText.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,117)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$TestTagText.Text = "<Test & Tag> - Were the power cables T&T compliant"
$Form.Controls.Add($TestTagText)

$TroubleshootText = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TroubleshootText.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(750,20)
$TroubleshootText.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,152)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$TroubleshootText.Text = "<Troubleshooting> - What steps were performed during the resolution"
$Form.Controls.Add($TroubleshootText)

$ResolutionText = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$ResolutionText.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(750,20)
$ResolutionText.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,187)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Consolas",14,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font
$ResolutionText.Text = "<Resolution/Workaround> - How you fixed the problem"
$Form.Controls.Add($ResolutionText)

# ----------END TEXT BOXES---------- #

# ----------CREATE BUTTONS---------- #
$Resetbutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Resetbutton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(810,11) 
$Resetbutton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,30) 
$Resetbutton.Text = "Reset" 
$Resetbutton.Add_Click({$AssetText.Text = "<Asset Number(s)> - Asset number(s) of any affected equipment"
                        $ErrorText.Text = "<Error Text> - Error message if applicable"
                        $IssueText.Text = "<Issue Text> - What the technician's observation is"
                        $TestTagText.Text = "<Test & Tag> - Were the power cables T&T compliant"
                        $TroubleShootText.Text = "<Troubleshooting> - What steps were performed during the resolution"
                        $ResolutionText.Text = "<Resolution/Workaround> - How you fixed the problem"}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($Resetbutton)

$Copybutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Copybutton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(810,187) 
$Copybutton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,30) 
$Copybutton.Text = "COPY"
$Copybutton.Add_Click({$TEMPLATE.Text.Trim() | Clip}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($Copybutton)

$Exitbutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Exitbutton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(810,222) 
$Exitbutton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,30) 
$Exitbutton.Text = "Exit" 
$Exitbutton.Add_Click({$Form.Close()})
$Form.Controls.Add($Exitbutton)
# ----------END BUTTONS---------- #

# ----------Text to Copy---------- #

$A = $AssetLabel + " " + $AssetText
$E = $ErrorLabel + " " + $ErrorText
$I = $IssueLabel + " " + $IssueText
$TT = $TestTagLabel + " " + $TestTagText
$TS = $TroubleshootLabel + " " + $TroubleshootText
$RW = $ResolutionLabel + " " + $ResolutionText

$TEMPLATE = $A, $E, $I, $TT, $TS, $RW

# ----------End Text to Copy---------- #



$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code, why is it not working as expected? Are there any error messages being displayed? That's a lot of code, contributors to this site prefer small examples of pieces of code that aren't working: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more clear. When I run the code, I receive the error "Method invocation failed because [System.Windows.Forms.Label] does not contain 
a method named 'op_Addition'." for lines 143-148. Then when I attempt to use my 'COPY' button to copy the information i want onto the clipboard I get the error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:130 char:24"

I am only new to stackoverflow and thought that posting the entire code would be of more help in diagnosing the problem i am having.
I appreciate any help you may be able to provide @mjsqu

Comment: You are missing labels properties. $AssetLabel.Text+ " " + $AssetText.Text . You are not clear in your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the 'text to copy' block

```
# ----------Text to Copy---------- #

$A = $AssetLabel + " " + $AssetText
$E = $ErrorLabel + " " + $ErrorText
$I = $IssueLabel + " " + $IssueText
$TT = $TestTagLabel + " " + $TestTagText
$TS = $TroubleshootLabel + " " + $TroubleshootText
$RW = $ResolutionLabel + " " + $ResolutionText

$TEMPLATE = $A, $E, $I, $TT, $TS, $RW
```

to the `$Copybutton.Add_Click({})` block and add the text property like so

```
$Copybutton.Add_Click({

    $A = $AssetLabel.Text + " " + $AssetText.Text
    $E = $ErrorLabel.Text + " " + $ErrorText.Text
    $I = $IssueLabel.Text + " " + $IssueText.Text
    $TT = $TestTagLabel.Text + " " + $TestTagText.Text
    $TS = $TroubleshootLabel.Text + " " + $TroubleshootText.Text
    $RW = $ResolutionLabel.Text + " " + $ResolutionText.Text

    $TEMPLATE = $A, $E, $I, $TT, $TS, $RW | foreach {$_.Trim()}
    $TEMPLATE | Clip
})
```

and the trim() you probably want that for each line input.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and has completely fixed my problem. Thanks for taking the time to look at my code. It does make more sense to have the text to copy block actually within the click function. @Nas

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate the **whole** `label` object instead of its `.Text` properties. Change this:

```
$A = $AssetLabel + " " + $AssetText
$E = $ErrorLabel + " " + $ErrorText
$I = $IssueLabel + " " + $IssueText
$TT = $TestTagLabel + " " + $TestTagText
$TS = $TroubleshootLabel + " " + $TroubleshootText
$RW = $ResolutionLabel + " " + $ResolutionText
```

to this:

```
$A = $AssetLabel.Text + " " + $AssetText.Text
$E = $ErrorLabel.Text + " " + $ErrorText.Text
$I = $IssueLabel.Text + " " + $IssueText.Text
$TT = $TestTagLabel.Text + " " + $TestTagText.Text
$TS = $TroubleshootLabel.Text + " " + $TroubleshootText.Text
$RW = $ResolutionLabel.Text + " " + $ResolutionText.Text
```

Also. You want to place this part into `.Add_Click` method for `$Copybutton`. And change **Clip** to accelerator class `Windows.Clipboard` with its `SetText` method.

```
$Copybutton.Add_Click({
$A = $AssetLabel.Text + " " + $AssetText.Text
$E = $ErrorLabel.Text + " " + $ErrorText.Text
$I = $IssueLabel.Text + " " + $IssueText.Text
$TT = $TestTagLabel.Text + " " + $TestTagText.Text
$TS = $TroubleshootLabel.Text + " " + $TroubleshootText.Text
$RW = $ResolutionLabel.Text + " " + $ResolutionText.Text

$TEMPLATE = $A.Trim(), $E.Trim(), $I.Trim(), $TT.Trim(), $TS.Trim(), $RW.Trim()
[Windows.Clipboard]::SetText($TEMPLATE)
})
```

Comment: Thankyou, This worked wonders with copying the text i needed. However when pasting the copied text it did not have the formating followed line by line. It definately was a step in the right direction however. @Kirill Pashkov